# A mass dropped on a piston

Tags: thermodynamics

Say a problem in which after an adiabatic process, during which we drop a mass onto a piston, we wait for equilibrium to be achieved, from a state A and B.  Between a state A and B, what is the process? Is it isochoric? Isobaric?

The problem which I face doesn't specify whether the volume stays constant...

Comment: Hint: external conditions (e.g., the weight of the freely-moving piston plus whatever's on top of it) determine the pressure in the gas.  Draw a free-body diagram.

Comment: The trick is to determine the work done as a result of the change in potential energy of the weight plus the external pressure times the change in volume of gas plus the change in potential energy of the piston.